# How to remove *all* green and blue light: xcalib and redshift seem not to?

Tags: linux, display, redshift

I'd like to have a `redshift`-style effect on my laptop screen but where I truly remove *all* green and blue light, leaving only red.  I've experimented with `redshift`, which doesn't seem to take it all the way, only redder, but neither it seems does `xcalib`...  I had thought I could get this by running this:

```
xcalib -blue 1 0 1 -a
xcalib -green 1 0 1 -a
```

But that seems to turn the screen orange rather than red -- perhaps it reduces the contrast in both directions (so makes the bottom end brighter too?).  I'm confident that I'm right, and that that isn't a trick of the light, because if i run instead

```
xcalib -red 1 99 1 -a
```

...then my black terminal turns definitely the sort of red that I wanted.

Is there any way that I can achieve what I want -- effectively, cut out *all* blue and green light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.

I'm using xrandr & the following script to adjust gamma and brightness on all connected monitors, depending of time of day.

```
#!/bin/bash

current_hour=$(date +%k)
red_gamma=1.0
green_gamma=1.0
blue_gamma=1.0
brightness=1

if (( current_hour >= 6 && current_hour <= 18 )); then
  # Daytime: normal blue light emissions, slight reduction in brightness
  red_gamma=1.0
  green_gamma=1.0
  blue_gamma=1.0
  brigthness=0.9
else
  # Nighttime: reduce blue light emissions & brightness
  red_gamma=1.0
  green_gamma=0.7
  blue_gamma=0.4
  brightness=0.5
fi

xrandr | grep " connected" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -i xrandr --output {} --gamma $red_gamma:$green_gamma:$blue_gamma --brightness $brightness
```

You can also use "xgamma" for the same thing if you don't want to use xrandr.

```
usage:  xgamma [-options]

where the available options are:
    -display host:dpy       or -d
    -quiet                  or -q
    -screen                 or -s
    -version                or -v
    -gamma f.f              Gamma Value
    -rgamma f.f             Red Gamma Value
    -ggamma f.f             Green Gamma Value
    -bgamma f.f             Blue Gamma Value
```

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot I even asked that question five years ago, but hopefully this will be helpful to someone struggling as I was!